# Parametrize on group level

Tags: testng

I want to parametrize groups in the testng.xml and get the data with a `DataProvider` afterwards.

1. I want to run a metagroup and a group included in the metagroup but with a different parameter. It seems, that if the group is included in the metagroup, it's not started a second time. My usecase is a website with different user- roles (the supergroup should test from admin perspective, the group1 should only test as visitor)

   ```
   <suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" parallel="false">
       <test name="Test1">
           <groups>
               <define name="supergroup">
                   <include name="group1" />
                   <include name="group2" />
               </define>
               <run>
                   <include name="supergroup">
                       <parameter name="config" value="super" />
                   </include>
                   <include name="group1">
                       <parameter name="config" value="first" />
                   </include>
               </run>
           </groups>
           <packages>
               <package name="com.company.test.*" />
           </packages>
       </test>
   </suite>
   ```
2. I want to get the parameters with a DataProvider and inject them into the test classes. The ITestContext seems not to afford the opportunity to access parameters defined below test- level

   ```
   @DataProvider(name = "test", parallel = false)
   public static Object[][] testDataProvider(ITestContext context){

       String config = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("config");

       Object[][] back = new Object[1][1];

       back[0] = new Object[] { config };

       return back;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do it like that:

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" parallel="false">
    <test name="SuperTest">
        <parameter name="config" value="super" />
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="group2" />
                <include name="group1" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.company.test.*" />
        </packages>
    </test>
    <test name="SubTest">
        <parameter name="config" value="sub" />
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="group1"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.company.test.*" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Though I seem not to get the group pattern